# Is there any difference between a parametric equation and a vector function?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vectors, parametric

Perhaps it's due to the fact that I'm currently tackling introductory material on parametric equations, but it seems to me at the moment that there is no real difference between a *set* of parametric equations and a vector function.

---

I'll give the standard example:

Let's say I have a parametric *curve* defined by the parametric *equations* $x=\cos(t)$ and $y=\sin(t)$. What stops me from defining $r(t) = \left\langle  x, \  y   \right\rangle  = \left\langle  \cos(t), \  \sin(t)   \right\rangle$, which describes the *exact same* parametric curve (the unit circle) as the parametric equations for $x$ and $y$?

---

Now I <strike>know</strike> *assume* that there has to be some difference between parametric equations and vector functions, but with the material I'm currently working with I can't seem to find a counter-example, or cases where they differ.

I also realize that the concept of parameterization is critical to fields like Differential Geometry (based on what I've read so far in *do Carmo's book*), and proofs of the big Integral Theorems (generalized Stokes' Theorem etc) rely on it, and this concept is something I want to understand rock solid.

Can anyone give an example, as to why a *set* of parametric equations are different from vector functions of the form $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^m}$, and furthermore as to why they are so important to theorems in higher-dimensions?

Comment: "Now I know that there has to be some difference..." - **how do you know this?**

Comment: A "parametric equation" _is_ the same as a vector-valued function. Using the term "parametric equation" is simply an informal way to hint that you think of the _range_ of the function as its most important property and the exact input-output dependence as something secondary.

Comment: They are different ways to represent the same concept

Comment: @Nij, well I *assumed* there must be some *difference*. The way textbook authors refer to parametric equations seem entirely different to the way they refer to vector valued functions, giving the impression that they were two separate concepts. In fact from the perhaps *poor* exposition that I've read, one text even made it seem as if parametric equations were in some way inherently more fundamental than vector functions.

Comment: @Nij, but then that begs the question, why are parametric equations even a *thing*. I mean why is *parameterization* referred to as commonly as it is in many texts, when authors could just say *"This is a vector function describing a curve"*?

Comment: Because not everybody has reached the point where vector spaces are something they know the existence of. But parametrisation follows naturally from several basic areas, and vector functions follow naturally from several others, some of which are the same.

Answer (score 1):

$F(x,y)=\langle x,y \rangle$ is a vector function $F:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2$. It describes a vector field. It is not a parameterized curve.

Comment: Cant it be a parametrized curve of 2 parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Well not all parametric equations define parametric curves. For example $x(s,t)=s$, $y(s,t)=t$ is not a parametric curve and is not a function $f\colon \Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}^n$. :) It is however the same as $\langle s,t\rangle$.

However if you mean parametric equation with only one parameter, it's the same thing. The parametric equations are the components of the vector function.